# Appcelerator Compiling Modules to Use

Tags: ios, module, titanium, appcelerator

I am looking for support in compiling the following module. I want to use this module for selecting multiple images from the gallery, but I cannot find the packaged module to install in appcelerator. How do I use this in my app for iOS [titanium-imagepicker](https://github.com/prashantsaini1/titanium-imagepicker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [compiled version](http://migaweb.de/ti.imagepicker-iphone-2.0.0.zip)

Please keep in mind: Ti SDK 8+ only!